# Alternative interpretation of the second law of thermo

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I have had this thought for a while and I was wondering whether it's valid.

1. Entropy is often described as the amount of "unuseable*" energy in a system
2. at a micro level, entropy is related to the number of states that can be reached
3. If we know the trajectory of a system, we can theoretically extract work from it.
4. Equations describe the trajectory of a system.
5. On the micro level, if you have a set of states that are all equipotential, the only way for entropy to increase is for a new state to exist... one that wasn't accounted for previously

So my interpretation is that entropy of a system is the energy of the system that is not contained in the labeled states/equations/bodies.  Entropy increases because our predictions are less and less accurate over time, so more of the energy of the system is unaccounted for.

Take for example a particle bouncing around in a box.  We account for its kinetic energy.  We account for some of its internal energy via temperature and mass.  Now imagine rather than going in a straight line, the ball is slightly moving back and forth across this line.  So there's some variance from a perfect fit from that line.  We can account for that variance in a few ways.  (1) we account for it as kinetic energy.  Because the ball is moving back and forth, it was actually at a higher velocity this whole time than we measured, so we increase the velocity put into the kinetic energy equation.  (2) we ascribe it to temperature.. the particle now has a higher RMS velocity because there is more variance in their trajectories.  Thus the ball has a higher temperature (3) we account for it as entropy, saying that there are more states the ball could occupy.

So my questions are: is this interpretation valid on any level?  If not, what's the problem, if so, is there a better way to phrase it?

Comment: A much better way to phrase the second law is as the definition of temperature. It avoids all misunderstandings about the meaning of "entropy".

Comment: But entropy can increase in ways that don't relate to what we normal think of as "temperature"... right?  Like if you're describing a ball flying through the air but your equation ignores the tiny number of particles that are getting knocked off the ball.. that would be an increase of entropy, right? but would not necessarily change the RMS speed of the air molecules... seems like it makes more sense to bundle it into a thing like "externalities" than insisting that the "missing" energy always is dissipated as heat

Comment: If you ignore the tiny particles and their motion, then T=0 and then automatically S=0.

Comment: The air particles would still have temperature as well as the ball... I'm referring to particles sublimating off the ball itself

Comment: And before you say "they would be reflected as a reduction in the mass of the ball"... that's only true if we choose to model it that way.  In an engine we would model such energy loss as "inefficiency" and assume it was dissipated as heat outside the system.  But there are other ways a system can lose energy besides heat.  Just from the system's perspective it will be heat unless you add terms to the equations which account for it as something other than heat

Comment: That's not an interpretation of thermodynamics, then, but just an ad-hoc model for a ball of sublimating stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my interpretation is that entropy of a system is the energy of the system that is not contained in the labeled states/equations/bodies. Entropy increases because our predictions are less and less accurate over time, so more of the energy of the system is unaccounted for.

This is essentially the information-theoretical interpretation of entropy. It is an interpretation, which means that others may disagree, but personally I subscribe to this view.

A comment:

> If we know the trajectory of a system, we can theoretically extract work from it.

The way I would phrase this is this: a reversible process is one whose trajectory we can predict with absolute certainty. Under this condition we can extract the maximum amount of work. Anything less than 100% certainty makes the process irreversible and results in less work extracted (more work consumed).

Comment: OK, I thought it might be equivalent to the information-theoretical interpretation.  I wanted to confirm. Thank you. 


"No, entropy is not energy and is not associated with usable energy"
Ahh, yes, "useable" was a typo.. I meant "unuseable".  Thank you

Comment: @scl If you edit "usable" in your post, I will edit out mine :)

Comment: "I assume you mean to say that a reversible process is a process whose microscopic trajectory is known"  

Actually, I did not mean it that way.  Maybe I'm incorrect (which is why I'm asking), but I did not mean to limit the statement to reversible processes.  I meant that if we can't make any meaningful predictions about the future state of a system, we can't extract meaningful work from it.  It seems super obvious to me, I'm thikning it must already be a concept, but I'm probably just not using the right word for the physical concepts.  Or maybe it's just wrong..

Comment: Haha, it's ok, I'll edit it with an asterisk so if anyone sees this they'll know what happened.

Comment: @scl On "meaningful predictions", I suppose I can see it your way: a reversible process is one for which we can make predictions with absolute certainty (classical mechanics). Anything else is irreversible (new microstates not predicted initially). Maximum work is obtained from the reversible process, irreversibilities always cost us work.

Comment: @scl Your edit makes it unclear if you are saying "usable" or "unusable". Just say usable.

Comment: I meant to ask.. could you point me to a source or something that describes the interpretation in a similar way to that?  Specifically mentioning the states that are accounted for in the equations?

Comment: You may find this useful: https://www.informationphilosopher.com/solutions/scientists/jaynes/Jaynes_Gibbs_Boltzmann.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144942/discussion-between-scl-and-themis).